# Keyframing in 3DS MAX 2014 SDK c++

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

I want to ask you guys to help me with creating keyframes in Max SDK C++.
What I've done:

- Created a Controller Plugin
- Inside the `getValue` function I've done my translations via code.
- I also wrote the `setValue` function.

Which I think manages keyframes and stores the controllers position in a given time in a given keyframe. In this way I achieved to be able to set keys manually, but I really would like, to work with the Auto Key turned on in Max.
On the other hand, I can't see the freshly added keys values. So please help me, how could I add keyframes?

Many Thanks:
Banderas

```
void maxProject3::GetValue(TimeValue t, void *ptr, Interval &valid, GetSetMethod method)
{

Point3 p3OurAbsValue(0, 0, 0);
tomb[0]=0;

//These positions stores my data they are globals
XPosition += (accX);
YPosition += (accY);
ZPosition += (accZ);

p3OurAbsValue.x = XPosition;
p3OurAbsValue.y = YPosition;
p3OurAbsValue.z = ZPosition;

   valid.Set(t,t+1); //This answer is only valid at the calling time.

   MatrixCtrl->GetValue(t, &p3OurAbsValue.y, valid, CTRL_RELATIVE);

   if (method == CTRL_ABSOLUTE)
   {

          Point3* p3InVal = (Point3*)ptr;
          *p3InVal = p3OurAbsValue;

   }
   else // CTRL_RELATIVE
   {
          //We do our translations on a Matrix
          Matrix3* m3InVal = (Matrix3*)ptr;
          //m3InVal->PreTranslate(p3OurAbsValue);
          m3InVal->PreRotateX(rotX);
          m3InVal->PreRotateY(rotY);
          m3InVal->PreRotateZ(rotZ);
   }
}

int maxProject3::NumSubs() { 
return 1; 
}

Animatable* maxProject3::SubAnim(int n) { 
return MatrixCtrl; 
}

void maxProject3::SetValue(TimeValue t, void *ptr, int commit, GetSetMethod method)
{
    Matrix3* m3InVal = (Matrix3*)ptr;
    MatrixCtrl->AddNewKey(t, ADDKEY_SELECT);
    MatrixCtrl->SetValue(t, &m3InVal, commit, CTRL_RELATIVE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To turn on the Auto key mode try using `AnimateOn()` before your transformation. Also add `AnimateOff()` to turn off the auto key mode in the end.

I did it in one of my project to create material id animation using auto key mode.

```
/** Auto key on*/
AnimateOn();

/** Creating material id animation */
for(int mtl_id = 1; mtl_id <= num_sub_mtl; ++mtl_id, time += time_step)
{
    mtl_modifier->GetParamBlock()->SetValue(MATMOD_MATID,time,mtl_id);
}

/** Auto key off*/
AnimateOff();
```

Also as a suggestion, use the max script listener to know whats happening when the animation is created using 3ds Max GUI. This will help you to recreate the animation using Max SDK.